# Cannot switch keyboard at GDM login

Tags: keyboard, login, gdm

Just a bit of a different question from [1014258](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014258/cannot-switch-keyboard-layout-at-gdm-login). I have an arabic keyboard installed on my system and sometimes I forget to switch it back to english before my computer suspends itself. When I go to log back in, my keyboard seems to be stuck in arabic, and either I can't switch it back, or it still writes right-to-left when I do, making it impossible for me to login unless I reboot the system.

When I press `super+space` it shows the languages change on the little notification pop-up and the language in the top bar updates, but when I type, it still types right-to-left and even if I type my password in backwards, it still doesn't work.

I tried doing as in [1014258](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014258/cannot-switch-keyboard-layout-at-gdm-login) and added a second user, and then looked at the login screen settings, but it only shows english, so I'm not sure what's going on.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 64 bit with english and arabic keyboards installed, and I'm using the gdm3 login (I believe, I'm not sure if that matters or not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by upgrading to ubuntu `20.04`, there must be some bug that was fixed in the new kernel release.